# If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$ and if $|H|$ and $|K|$ are relatively prime, prove that $H\cap K=\{1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I've worked through this problem but I'm not sure if my logic is correct. This is my attempt of proof:

Suppose $H\cap K\neq{\{1\}}$ then exists $a\neq{1}\in H\cap K$ such that $a\in H\wedge a\in K$. We know that $1=|H|r+|K|s$, then:

$a=a^{|H|r+|K|s}=(a^{r})^{|H|}(a^{s})^{|K|}=1$ !

That way $a=1$ and $H\cap K=\{1\}$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: This works; you do not need to assume the intersection is nontrivial, though. Just take an element in the intersection, and show it is trivial, thus showing $H\cap K\subseteq \{1\}$. Alternatively, since you know that the order of an element must divide the order of the group, if $a\in H\cap K$, then the order of $a$ divides both $|H|$ and $|K|$....

Comment: Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So could I just said $ord(a)||H|$ and $ord(a)||K|$ then because $(|H|,|K|)=1$ then $ord(a)|1$ and so $ord(a)=1$?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. Or, as Lord Shark notes, since $H\cap K$ is a subgroup of both $H$ and $K$, it has order dividing both $|H|$ and $|K|$ and hence has order $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof works. You should strive to use Lagranges theorem, as its used quite frequently in group theory courses. For example:

$H$ $\cap$ $K$ is a subgroup in for any group where $H$ and $K$ are subgroups. It is a subgroup of $H$ and it is a subgroup of $K$, since we are taking the intersection. So |$H \cap K$| divides |$H$| and |$H \cap K$| divides |K|.

But the only positive number(s) that divide both |$H$| and |$K$| is $1$, by definition of what it means to be coprime. Hence the intersection of $H$ and $K$ must be the trivial group, namely {$1$}. So the order is $1$.

Answer (score 3):

By Lagrange's theorem $|H\cap K|$ divides both $|H|,|K|$ and therefore $|H\cap K|=1$ because $\text{gcd}(|H|,|K|)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is fine.

Hint: another proof requires at least the following facts (in no particular order):

- Lagrange's Theorem.
- The intersection of any two subgroups of a group $G$ is a subgroup of $G$.
- For natural numbers $k,x,y$, if $k\mid x$ and $k\mid y$ but $x,y$ are coprime, then $k=1$.
- If $H\le K$ and $K\le G$, then $H\le G$; that is, the relation of being a subgroup is transitive.
- The trivial group is unique up to isomorphism.
- The trivial group is isomorphic to a subgroup of each group $G$; namely, the subgroup with underlying set $\{e_G\}$.
- The trivial group has order one.
- Isomorphisms preserve order.
- Any subgroup of a group is itself a group.